# Video card error: Driver or Hardware?

Tags: cpu, gpu, reboot

Last night, I came home to find that one of my screens on my PC was grey with loads of white lines through it. I had to force it shut down, and I saw the error "Video Card Error". I have the new AMD Crimson Driver which I've heard can be buggy.

It has done this kind of thing when it over heats but the PC was idle with the screens off so I wouldn't think it got that hot.

Another thing to note was that I swapped from a Pentium G3258 to an i5 4690k, which seemed fine until I got this thing... What do you guys think was the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar either with the specified graphics card.
According to your description there is no doubt that the problem lies in overheating or a bad driver.

Things you should try:

- Check if you have the proper updated driver.
- Check if graphics card is plugged in properly in its slot.
- Check if graphics card fan is working, well ventilated and free of heavy dust.
- Search in the graphics card manufacturer's forum and contact graphics card manufacturer's support. Report your problem. Request a new driver or fix.
- If you're using a desktop computer, check if the graphics card has sufficient power.
- Add some sort of cooling to the graphics card and temperature control.

For temperature control: "Open Hardware Monitor".

Also, the issues you just mentioned usually mean that your graphics card is pretty much dead. Therefore I would try contacting the manufacturer first.

Comment: Thanks. I've only had my graphics card for a year though. Not even that. I got it February last year. Do you still think It could be dead? I cleaned the PC out with a can of air only a couple of weeks ago. It's been fine power wise, I think.

Comment: The GPU might not be in properly, as I got a CPU upgrade by my manufacturer and they would have had to take it out. I'll have a check later.

Comment: Well it' not working properly. Those graphic glitches usually appear on theses circunstances: Card Overheat / Overclock; faulty cable or driver; card may not be properly plugged.. I assume that you didnt do overclocking and that your Hardware is still under warranty. If so, 1st speak with your vendor. They must check the problem and fix it. Hope you get oit fixed. Best Regards;